# Question on definition of operator norm and $\frac{x}{||x||}$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

[image: Definition]

Hi, I'm not sure how $Fx = \|x\| F\left(\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right)$ derives the first equation to the second equation.

Thank you!

Comment: Please type questions instead of posting images. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
\|F\|_1 = \sup\{ \| Fx \|\colon x \in U,\ \|x \| \le 1 \}
$$
and
$$
\|F\|_2 = \sup\{ \| Fx \|\colon x \in U,\ \|x \| = 1 \}.
$$
We want to prove that $\|F\|_1 = \|F\|_2$. Obviously $\|F\|_1 \ge \|F\|_2$, hence we are left with proving that
$$
\|F\|_1 \le \|F\|_2.
$$
To this end let $x \in U$ with $\|x\|\le 1$. Then $y := x/\|x\|$ has norm $\|y\|=1$ and
$$
Fx = \|x\|F(x/\|x\|) = \|x\| Fy \le Fy,
$$
because $\|x\|\le 1$. In other words, for every $x$ with norm less that or equal to one we can find $y$ with norm equal to one such that $\|Fx\| \le \|Fy\|$. But this is exactly what we need, since we proved that for every element in the set
$$
\{ \| Fx \|\colon x \in U,\ \|x \| \le 1 \}
$$
there exists at least as big element in the set
$$
\{ \| Fx \|\colon x \in U,\ \|x \| = 1 \}.
$$

Comment: Thank you @Xen. May I ask why is it true that $\| Fx\|  \leq \|  F\| \| x\|,  \forall x \in U$ here?

Comment: @2pirsquared Sure, but I am not exactly sure that we used this inequality. I have added some clarifications.

Comment: thank so much for your help! You explanation is very clear! The inequality is actually the next line in my notes. But I'm not sure how we got the inequality from what we have above. Actually, the only problem I have is to figure out why $ \|F\| \frac{x}{\|x\|} \| \leq \|F\|$

Comment: *figure out why $ \|F (\frac{x}{\|x\|}) \| \leq \|F\|, \forall x$

Comment: @2pirsquared Oh, that is easy. Since $x/\|x\|$ has norm $1$, the norm $\|F(x/\|x\|)\|$ is an element of the set $\{\|Fy\|\colon y \in U,\ \|y\|\le 1\}$, and $\|F\|$ is the supremum of this set.

Answer (score 2):

To show the equivalence of the two equations, we need to show that $\|Fx\|$ cannot attain supremum when $\|x\| < 1$.

By $Fx = \|x\|F\left(\dfrac x{\|x\|}\right)$ we have for $\|x\| < 1$:

$$\begin{align}\|Fx\| &= \left\|\left(\|x\|F\left(\dfrac x{\|x\|}\right)\right)\right\|\\&=\|x\|\left\|F\left(\dfrac x{\|x\|}\right)\right\| \\&< \left\|F\left(\dfrac x{\|x\|}\right)\right\| \\&\le \sup \big\{\|Fx\|\,\,\big|\,\,x\in U, \|x\|\le1\big\}\end{align}$$

since $\left\|\dfrac x{\|x\|}\right\| = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the sets
$$ V_1=\{\|Fx\|:\|x\|\le 1\} \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad V_2=\{\|Fx\|:\|x\|=1\}. $$
We want to prove the statement $$\sup V_1 = \sup V_2. $$
Since $V_1\supset V_2$, we know $\sup V_1\ge\sup V_2. $

By the definition of the supremum, we can choose $v_\epsilon\in V_1$, such that $$ \|Fv_\epsilon \|\ge \sup V_1-\epsilon \qquad\mbox{for any}\ \epsilon>0.$$
Now put $\tilde v_\epsilon=v_\epsilon/\|v_\epsilon\|\in V_2$. By linearity of $F$ and $\|v_\epsilon\|\le 1$ we obtain
$$ \|F\tilde v_\epsilon\| = \frac{\|Fv_\epsilon\|}{\|v_\epsilon\|}\ge \|Fv_\epsilon\|\ge \sup V_1+\epsilon.$$
Since $\tilde v_\epsilon\in V_2$, this implies $\sup V_2\ge \sup V_1+\epsilon$. Taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ then yields $\sup V_2\ge \sup V_1$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|\cdot\|_*$ be the second definition.

We must have $\|F\|_* \le \|F\|$.

Let $u_n$ be a sequence with $\|u_n\| \le 1$ such that $\|Fu_n\| \to \|F\|$.

Note that $\|F u_n\| \le \| F{u_n \over \|u_n\|} \| \le \|F\|$, so $\| F{u_n \over \|u_n\|} \|  \to \|F\|$.

Since $\| F{u_n \over \|u_n\|} \| \le \|F\|_*$ we see that
$\|F\|_* = \|F\|$.